# Accelerate SPARQL query - filtering out rows which contain

Tags: filter, sparql

I am currently working with SPARQL (and TopBraidComposer). I have a query which only brings back matching literals, and then filters out the literals based on not wanting certain categories.

Currently, this query is taking a long time to run, and I think it is my FILTER which is causing the delay. I was wondering if someone would have a better and faster way of filtering out (NOT returning) rows which contain a set of key words (ex. cat1, cat2, cat3).

As of now, I am using;

```
SELECT ?category
WHERE {
   ?s1 ?p ?category .
   ?s2 ?p ?category .

    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat1") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat2") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat3") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat4") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat6") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat8") .
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear how much you've trimmed down your example, but the code you presented is doing more work than it needs to.

```
SELECT ?category
WHERE {
   ?s1 ?p ?category .
   ?s2 ?p ?category .

    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat1") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat2") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat3") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat4") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat6") .
    FILTER (str(?category) != "Cat8") .
}
```

Suppose your data has

```
:a :p "Cat0" .
:b :p "Cat0" .
```

Then the bindings for `?s1`, `?s2`, `?p?` and `?category` can be

```
?s1 ?s2 ?p ?category
--------------------
:a  :a  :p "Cat0"
:a  :b  :p "Cat0"
:b  :b  :p "Cat0"
:b  :a  :p "Cat0"
```

That's four ways to select `"Cat0"`.  You said that you want literals, but right now you're hitting every kind of `?category` and applying `str` to it multiple times. You might do this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?category
WHERE {
   ?s ?p ?category .
   FILTER( isLiteral(?category) &&
           !(str(?category) in ("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", 
                                "Cat4", "Cat6", "Cat8")) )
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested, and it works :). I did not realise how much more work my original query was requiring (thank you for including an example). Thank you for your help!